# Socket server vs http server for iOS app

Tags: ios, sql, web-services, sockets, networking

Im building a social app that requires a lot of user profiles and statuses. I currently have a protegeSQL setup, that communicates with a python script that is an api for my app's database.  I need to make this as scalable as possible so I was thinking of using sockets to connect the iPhone to the script, would this be a good approach? Or rather, should I just use plain HTTP?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think using socket is a good/better way for a social app.

Socket connection is mainly byte stream communication, and AFAIK it is commonly used in (probably old) proprietary protocols for information exchange. It has the advantage of "platform independent"(any platform can handle byte stream) and slightly performance edge if both server and client sides are well written/optimized.

On the other hand, HTTP is easier to use and there are many frameworks, libraries, documentations, resources helping you optimize the business requirements. Depending on the server stacks you are using, and the client side iOS (or plus Android), HTTP+JSON can be sufficient.

In the following example, you can see just two lines will get data from a HTTP web service interface. This example searches "skateboarding dog" on Youtube.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=skateboarding+dog&start-index=21&max-results=10&v=2&alt=json"]];
        NSDictionary* content = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"content\n%@", content);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for! Also, would you recommend writing my own HTTP service, or opting out for an already built solution, like parse?

Comment: @Lou I'm no expert on server apps building. I only wrote some small python scripts for very simple tasks like registration code generator. With limited experience, I would recommend using existing frameworks if you want to build social networking services.